# How do I change some strings in an ODT file?

Tags: c#, zip, odt

I have an .odt wordprocessing file, to be processed with libre office or Word, and I need to replace a bunch (20+) of strings in the text with other text.
I know an .odt file is really a .zip file, containing .xml files and that i need to access content.xml.
Do I unzip the content.xml to a stream, deserialize that and use LINQ or something?
Or is there an easier way, using some ready-made library?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using .Net 4.5 you can make use of the new System.IO.Compression namespace.  There are a couple articles out there on how to do it.  Here's one http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/zip-and-unzip-files-programmatically-in-c.htm
 which I've found useful.